# Python: Index in for loop is resetting without a reason

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

First of all, I would like to apologize for my english since it is not my native language.

I'm having a quite crazy problem with the following code:

```
linecounter = []

for i in range(20):
    linecounter.append("Color "+str(i)+"\n")


for line in linecounter:
    color_list = range(20)
    for j in range(len(color_list)):
        stri = "Color " + str(j+1)
        if stri in line:
            print j
```

The result I expect:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19

The result I'm getting:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
0
9
0
10
0
11
0
12
0
13
0
14
0
15
0
16
0
17
0
18

Can somebody tell me how I get this result or how I get the result I want?

I would like to thank everyone who answers.

Sincerely, Nikster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those extra zeroes are being printed because of the way the `in` operator works for strings. When `line` is `"Color10"` and `stri` is `"Color1"`, then `if stri in line` evaluates to True, and prints the value of j, which is zero at the time.

Try using an equality comparison instead of `in`. You would also need to add a newline to the end of `stri` so that they compare properly.

```
    stri = "Color " + str(j+1) + "\n"
    if stri == line:
        print j
```

This will print the numbers from 0 through 18. I don't entirely understand what you're trying to do, but if you want 19 to get printed, you could try not adding 1 to j:

```
    stri = "Color " + str(j) + "\n"
    if stri == line:
        print j
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I could solve my problem with a variation of your answer

Answer (score 0):

Strange logic but:

```
linecounter = []

for i in range(20):
    linecounter.append("Color "+str(i))


for line in linecounter:
    color_list = range(20)
    for j in range(len(color_list)):
        stri = "Color " + str(j+1)
        if stri == line:
            print j
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it only solves the problem of this example. In my main program, I read the lines from a text file, so this doesn't realy helps me.

Comment: Just add new line'\n'
    `linecounter.append("Color "+str(i)+"\n")

    stri = "Color " + str(j+1)+"\n" `